# How can I add 'view mode' to screen options for pages and cpts?

Tags: wp-admin

The 'screen options' for posts has a view mode option, enabling switching between 'list' and 'excerpt' view (in which for the latter the except appears below the title).

How can I add such an option to pages (support for excerpts is enabled) and cpts which support excerpts?

Answer (score 2):

Currently the *excerpt view* is limited to **non-hierarchical** post types.

We are able to filter the view mode in the *Screen Options*:

[image: view mode]

with the `view_mode_post_types` filter, introduced within ticket [#22222](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22222) in changeset [#35357](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/35357):

```
/**
 * Filters the post types that have different view mode options.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 *
 * @param array $view_mode_post_types Array of post types that can change view modes.
 *                                    Default hierarchical post types with show_ui on.
 */
$view_mode_post_types = apply_filters( 'view_mode_post_types', $view_mode_post_types );
```

but because of this check in [`WP_Posts_List_Table::column_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_posts_list_table/column_title/):

```
if ( 
       ! is_post_type_hierarchical( $this->screen->post_type ) 
    && 'excerpt' === $mode 
    && current_user_can( 'read_post', $post->ID ) 
) {
     echo esc_html( get_the_excerpt() );
}
```

we're not able to modify this check directly to add support for hierarchical post types.

*There are some hackish workarounds possible but I didn't explore it further, as the ones I have in mind, might not be stable here.*

ps: I think there's a typo in the inline documentation:

> Default hierarchical post types with show_ui on.

should be

> Default non-hierarchical post types with show_ui on.

because the default ones are <sup>[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/10177e7fbbf163f7204c36358f23660f180cab58/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-screen.php#L1192)</sup>:

```
$view_mode_post_types = get_post_types( 
    array( 'hierarchical' => false, 'show_ui' => true ) 
);
```

**Update**: The documentation for the filter has been fixed by ticket [#41730](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41730)

Comment: Thanks. Oh well. (Apparently, there was a point at which a now-fixed bug caused excerpts to be shown on hierarchical posts - https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32187.)

Comment: I wonder if the `view_mode_post_types filter` output should be used in core, instead of this `is_post_type_hierarchical()` check,, to have it in sync?

Comment: I don't know enough to understand much of this, but extending the view option to all posts/pages would be useful.

Comment: Maybe this will be adjusted in the core, in the future? But the list tables are getting a possible upgrade with React + Rest, so it will be interesting to follow it [here](https://github.com/WP-API/new-list-tables)